# Magento not working well with ExpressionEngine

Tags: magento-1.6, session

I'm writing an ExpressionEngine (2.7.2) plugin to return some information about the user's current Magento (v 1.4.0.1) session.

We currently have EE and Magento working together on our site with EE 2.5.2 and Mage 1.0.4.1, I am attempting to update Magento to 1.8 and EE to 2.7.2. This is a development system with an EE 2.7.2 and a few changes to the templates to build a lot of the EE stuff into plugins and Extensions/Modules and this is stumping me.

The Magento in this development copy is currently 1.4.0.1, I intend to upgrade it after I get them working together.

The function below is supposed to return this JSON:

```
{"result":{"name":"","cart_url":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/store\/checkout\/cart\/","log_url":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/login","cart_count":0}}
```

But is is returning the data PLUS exceptions about Varien Autoload.

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning:
>   include(Stats.php) ... failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory  in C:\wamp\www\store\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93'...

Plugin Function:

```
 public function getusernav() {
     include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . '/srv/www/htdocs/store/app/Mage.php');
     umask(0);
     Mage::app();
     $pidsess                         = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
     $this->return_data["name"]       = "";
     $this->return_data["cart_url"]   = "";
     $this->return_data["log_url"]    = "";
     $cart                            = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
     $magsession                      = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');        
     $this->return_data["cart_count"] = $cart->getItemsCount();

     $this->return_data["cart_url"]   = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/store/checkout/cart/";
     $this->return_data["log_url"]    = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/login";
     if ($magsession->isLoggedIn() == true) {
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/customer")->load($magsession->getCustomerId()); 
         $this->return_data["name"]       = "Welcome, ".$customer->getName()."!";
     }
     return json_encode(array('result' => $this->return_data));
 }
```

Can anyone help out here? How can I prevent Magento from trying to autoload the EE classes?

Is there a way to unload the Magento stuff at the end of the function without actually ending the user's Magento session?

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent it and you can't 'unload' Magento since all the classes are already included in the code.

The only possible option would be to rewrite the Varien autoload function getting it to ignore the files you want. But I would strongly advice against that since it's a pretty dirty core hack.

Another option would be to write a second layer that returns Magento data through, for example, and API which you can then use in your function. Basically seperating the Magento code from your current function.

Comment: I think I may have figure out a way to do it but it basically involves moving the function to an external script and calling it via curl. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: It worked exactly as I expected by doing as I described above.

Comment: Perfect :) just keep in mind it does generate some network overhead. But I guess it's a minor trade off